# Using different edge line types in qgraph

Tags: par, r-qgraph

I am using `qgraph` package to plot network of correlations, which show both positive and negative values. I need a gray scale plot due to journal restrictions, so color of nodes can be easily set but I'm having difficulties with edges. I would like to set a different line type for positive (`"solid"`) and negative (`"dashed"`) correlations, so we don't need gray code for nodes and also for edges. The argument `lty` in ´qgraph`only allows for one type of line for the whole plot, how can I get it to work?

Here's a tentative solution

```
qgraph(polys$rho, groups = structure_hscl, 
         color= c("white","gray","gray25"),
         borders=TRUE, trans=FALSE, details=TRUE,
         bonf=TRUE, alpha=.05,
         normalize =TRUE, vsize=3, 
         threshold= .2, labels=labels_hscl,
         layout="spring", graph="pcor", 
         lty = c("solid","dashed")   # this obviously doesn't work )
```

Thanks a lot beforehand!

Answer (score 0):

It seems that lty needs to be a *vector* of suitable values. So how do we know which edges should be dashed and which solid? I'll demonstrate one way to get the job done using the *bfi* data from the psych package.

```
library(psych)
library(qgraph)
data(bfi)

persvars <- bfi[,1:25]
```

Let's then create a temporary graph and infer which lines to draw as dashed based on the colors:

```
hackgraph <- qgraph(cor(persvars,use = "pa"), fade = FALSE, layout = "spring", graph = "pcor")

edgecolor <- hackgraph$graphAttributes$Edges$color
unique(hackgraph$graphAttributes$Edges$color)
```

Setting `fade = FALSE` above reduced the colors to a manageable number: now we know that positive edges are either "#009900" or "darkgreen" in color. So all we need to do is to form a new vector as:

```
linetype <- ifelse( (edgecolor == "#009900" | edgecolor =="darkgreen"), 1, 2)
```

We can then draw the desired graph based on these line types:

```
qgraph(cor(persvars,use = "pa"), layout = "spring", graph = "pcor", lty = linetype)
```

[image: Graph with negative edges as dashed lines]